# How to apply topic modeling?

Tags: information-retrieval, topic-modeling

I have 10000 tweets for 5 topics. Assume I know the ground truth (the actual topic of each tweet) and I group the tweets into 5 documents where each document contain tweets for a particular topic. Then I apply LDA on to the 5 documents with number of topics set to 5. In which case I get good topic words.

Now If I don't know the ground truth of tweets, how do I make input documents in a way that LDA will still give me good topic words describing the 5 topics.

What if I create input documents by randomly selecting a sample of tweets? What if this ends up with similar topic mixtures for input documents? Should LDA still find good topic words as in the case of 1st paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your problem is about topic modeling on short texts (Tweets). One approach is to combine Tweets into long pseudo-documents before training LDA. Another one is to assume that there is only one topic per document/Tweet.

In the case that you don't know the ground truth labels of Tweets, you might want to try the one-topic-per-document topic model (i.e. mixture-of-unigrams). The model details are described in:

Jianhua Yin and Jianyong Wang. 2014. A Dirichlet Multinomial Mixture Model-based Approach for Short Text Clustering. In Proceedings of the 20th ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining, pages 233–242.

You can find my Java implementations for this model and LDA at http://jldadmm.sourceforge.net/ Assumed that you know ground truth labels, you can also use my implementation to compare these topic models in document clustering task.

If you'd like to evaluate topic coherence (i.e. evaluate how good topic words), I would suggest you to have a look at the Palmetto toolkit (https://github.com/AKSW/Palmetto) which implements the topic coherence calculations.